# Android отправка файла другому приложению

Tags: android, android-intent

Пытаюсь отправить через Intent текстовый файл в ВК, который перед этим создал и сохранил во внутреннем хранилище. Однако пишет что не поддерживает данный тип файлов? Файл имеет расширение .txt

```
File file = new File(ActivitySettings.this.getFilesDir(), fileName);
// создаём новое намерение
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

// устанавливаем флаг для того, чтобы дать внешнему 
// приложению пользоваться нашим FileProvider
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

// генерируем URI, я определил полномочие как ID приложения в манифесте, 
// последний параметр это файл, который я хочу открыть
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ActivitySettings.this, 
                                     BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, 
                                     file);
intent.setData(uri);

// подтвердите, что устройство может открыть этот файл!
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    if (intent.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: ВК не поддерживает выгрузкy txt файлов

Comment: @Flippy, какой текстовый формат поддерживает?

Comment: Попробуйте прикреплять `uri` таким образом: `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);` и ещё миме-тип наверное нужно указать, только какой ему нужен... `intent.setType("?/?");`

Comment: @RodGers точно не знаю но всегда дублируйте последнюю букву в расширении файла тоесть .apk -> .apkk